# Como recuperar as funções de um editor clonado?

Tags: jquery, editor-de-texto, clone, summernote

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu estou adicionando dinamicamente o **summernote** abaixo em verde. Estou clonando na verdade os de cima. Claro que ia ter um problema com isso senão não seria programação. As funções dos editores adicionados não funcionam. Alguém saberia me dizer o que eu devo fazer para contornar tal problema?

Estou usando o código abaixo para adicioná-lo.

```
$(document).on('click', '.adicionar', function() {
    var content = $("#perguntas_formatadas").html();
    $("#clone_perguntas_formatadas").append(content);
    $("#clone_perguntas_formatadas .form-group").attr("data-remove", 1);
});
```

Comment: Já experimentou voltar a aplicar o summernote ao elemento clonado? Algo como `$('#clone_perguntas_formatadas').summernote();`

Answer (score 0):

Nunca usei Summernote, mas vendo a [documentação básica da API](http://summernote.org/getting-started/#basic-api) existe as seguintes funções para obter o conteúdo digitado (em HTML) e também há como definir um conteúdo, inserindo dentro de um Summernote já existente, respectivamente:

```
$('#summernote').summernote('code');
$('#summernote').summernote('code', markupStr);
```

---

Então basicamente:

```js
// Inicia o primeiro Summernote:
$('div#primeiro').summernote()
   .summernote('code', '<b>Esse</b> é o <u>primeiro</u> summernote');

// Excuta quando clicar em "Copiar":
$('#copiar').on('click', function() {

  // Copia o conteúdo do primeiro Summernote:
  CodigoDoPrimeiroSummerNote = $('div#primeiro').summernote('code');
  
  // Cria outros Summernote clonados do primeiro:
  $('<x-summernote></x-summernote>').appendTo('#clones');

  $('x-summernote').last().summernote()
    .summernote('code', CodigoDoPrimeiroSummerNote);

});
```

```html
<!-- Bibliotecas externas (JQuery, Bootstrap, Summernote...): --><link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script><script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script><link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.6/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet"><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.6/summernote.js"></script>

<div id="primeiro"></div>

<button id="copiar" class="btn">Copiar</button>

<div id="clones"></div>
```